# HELD UP meaning in a specific context

Tags: phrases

I came across a short conversation which is writen below:

> A: I like your luggage.
>   B: It looks nice but it hasn't held up well.

What did the person B mean? and what the meaning of held up well is here?

Comment: See Collins' [definition #6](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-up).

Answer (score 1):

> [**hold up**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-up) (phrasal verb):  9. to survive or last

Something which *holds up* (over time) is something that continues to be in good condition, or which is still valid, true, or useful. Examples:

> Even though Newton's Laws of Motion are no longer considered completely accurate, especially for subatomic particles, the fundamental formulas such as *F = ma* still **hold up** perfectly well for most physical objects.
>
> Although *The Wizard of Oz* was filmed in the late 1930s, its popularity has **held up** remarkably well, even 80 years later.
>
> I bought this jacket back when I was in university, and it's still my favorite, although you can see it hasn't really **held up** all that well.